# React useState toggle is only toggling once

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to toggle a single button so that it can hide/show elements using useState.
But the state is changing only once. That is on first Click the state toggles but not for the further clicks and I don't understand why
Here is my code

```js
const Viewer: React.FC<InputProps> = props => {
    const [isToggled, setToggled] = useState(false);
    const viewerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        viewer(
            {
                path: RESOURCE
            },
            viewerRef.current as HTMLDivElement
        ).then(instance => {
            const { elementManager } = instance;
            instance.setHeaderItems(header => {
                header.push({
                    type: TOGGLE_BUTTON,
                    img: TOGGLE_ICON,
                    title: "Show Elements",
                    onClick: async () => {
                        setToggled(!isToggled);
                        console.info("isToggled", isToggled);
                        if (elementManager) {
                            const allElements = elementManager.getAnnotationsList();
                            if (isToggled == true) {
                                elementManager.showElements(allElements);
                                console.info("shown");
                            } else {
                                elementManager.hideElements(allElements);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: try adding isToggled in the dependency array of useEffect hook. eg. useEffect(()=>{…rest of code},[isToggled])

Answer (score 0):

useEffect react hook only runs on each render. Since you're not giving any dependencies on dependency array, it has been executed once by clicking on button after the initial rendering. Therefore, add **isToggled** state inside the dependency array of the useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `isToggled` to the dependency array, it should fix your issue.

Also it's a good practice when setting state that depends on the state to pass in a function to the state setter.  For example `setToggled(!isToggled)` should be `setToggled(previousToggledValue => !previousToggledValue)`.  This way you avoid any race conditions.